# Using .jar file in Tomcat Server

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, tomcat6

I'm trying to use `colt.jar` file into my project in Tomcat Server. I have tried to put it into WEB-INF/lib/ , /lib even also in MyProject/lib/. none of them are working. Previously, I have used jar files like Jama-1.0.2.jar or servlet-api.jar and they were working pretty fine. I have tried to use it in my local machine importing the jar file with Eclipse, it works fine. But no idea why not working on the Server side.

Any suggestion please?

ADDED LATER :::: I have added the classpath and then during compilation it did not give me any error. But eventually during runtime, the methods (included to that class) are not working. It's not giving any error. It simply does not proceed with the execution. Need Help :(

Comment: When I try to compile my java file, it simply doesn't find the class..

Comment: you have to include this jar in compilation classpath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are confused between two different things:

1. Having the jar on your classpath when compiling your own classes.
2. Having the jar available at runtime

If you use Eclipse for Java EE developers (see http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and create a dynamic web project instead of a regular java project, then jars placed into WEB-INF/lib will automatically be added to the classpath for compilation, and will also be added to the WAR archive that will be deployed to Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. I understand that. But what should I do to make it work on server side?

Comment: Yes.. I could make it to add the classpath .. Thanks :)

Comment: If you don't get any class not found exceptions, then this part of your problem had been solved. You could double check by looking if colt.jar is included within the actual .war that is deployed to Tomcat. On your filesystem, just cd to the location where you installed Tomcat and inspect what's there. If colt.jar itself "doesn't work" you'd best open a new question for that.